# What is an Android.mk file

Tags: android

A project that I am trying to build has one of these, and I want to know exactly which tools are needed to build the project. I see some reference to NDK when I search but is that the only tool? It appears that this file is making a jar file, I see no reference to native code (c++).

Comment: make file? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)

Comment: I should mention that this is a different application and not the sample application.

Comment: I'm trying to share the preferences file between two apps and one commenter mentioned this file had to be modified for this, adding 'LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := shared' to it. my apps don't even have this file in the first place, but it thought I'd add this comment as a possible reason for having this file.

Answer (score 5):

the best answer to your question is reading this article:

**Android.mk file syntax specification**

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/4e159d95ebf23b5f72bb707b0cb1518ef96b3d03/docs/ANDROID-MK.TXT

after reading it you can figure out the idea behind the android.mk file.

cheers

Comment: Dead link. This is why responses that are only links are not good.

Comment: Sorry, that link contains a lot of text. I don't think it will get out of access.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/4e159d95ebf23b5f72bb707b0cb1518ef96b3d03/docs/ANDROID-MK.TXT

Answer (score 4):

The Android.mk files in the SDK samples are required to properly include the samples in the SDK build (if you are actually venturing into that territory). These have no bearing on what you are doing when you use the sample. To the OP, I'm not sure if you are using a sample project, but if you are, you can ignore this file.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some of the Android sample code come with an Android.mk file for no apparent reason -- maybe this gets auto-generated upon project creation if you happen to have the NDK installed or something. Android.mk does seem to be an NDK-specific thing.

So if there's really no native code involved, then if you're looking to build from the command line, make sure you have the JDK, Ant, and Android SDK installed.

Then take a look at

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject

After you run the "android update project ..." step, you should hopefully be able to do an "ant debug" to build the application.

Comment: What's your point? This doesn't seem to contradict anything I said about `Android.mk` not being needed for non-NDK development.